# Can you travel to Lithuania as a vaccinated US citizen?

Tags: international-travel, us-citizens, lithuania

I feel like I keep getting contradictory answers from websites. The US embassy in Lithuania websites states no but at the same time the website and other official Lithuanian sites state stuff like this as an addendum to what's been said.

"Persons who already had the virus or have been vaccinated following the full vaccination schedule will not be required to test or self-isolate provided they have a medical certificate or vaccination certificate (in one of the official languages of European Union) confirming that they had the virus within 180 days prior to the entry or their vaccination." https://urm.lt/default/en/important-covid19

Lithuania isn't exactly a hotspot for tourism so I can't really find any Americans or sites really confirming one or the other.

Comment: No, since you don't fulfill the conditions stated in **Border questions and transit through the territory of Lithuania**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.